# how to successfully add a foreign key constraint to your Database table in laravel using eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a database containing two Tables(students, payments) with **id** as primary key and another column `studentID` within the **students** Table. Am making **studentID** a foreign key in payments Table.

I am getting this error message:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column
>   'studentID' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `payments` add
>   constraint `payments_studentid_foreign` foreign key (`studentID`)
>   references `students` (`id`))

The studentID exists in both columns, what could be the possible solution to this. below is what I have done

students table

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('studentID');
            $table->string('Programme');
            $table->string('cLevel');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('surName');
        });
    }
```

payments table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreign('studentID')->references('id')->on('students');
            $table->string('feeType');
            $table->string('Year');
            $table->double('amount', 15,3);
            $table->string('paidBy');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: `studentId` should be a column in your `payments` table, not your `students` table

Comment: Yeah, you have to add it first, before the foreign key constrain

Comment: please i have it on both tables

Comment: "_please i have it on both tables_" No you don't. You need `$table->unsignedBigInteger('studentID');` before your `$table->foreign('studentID') ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently adding the student id 2 times on the students table.

`$table->id();` is a helper which makes an Unsigned Big Integer column with an auto-incrementing ID

So on your students table delete this line:

```
$table->bigInteger('studentID');
```

On your payments table you should add a new column with the id and the foreign key. Note that it is very important to have the same type for your foreign key as the original table so in this case a unsigned big integer:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('studentID');
$table->foreign('studentID')->references('id')->on('students');
```

PS: since you are a beginner, you should try to follow Laravel conventions for your naming. This will help in linking the relationships in your code.

The convention would be to rename studentID to student_id

Comment: How do i insert into the foreign Key studentID. Am getting errors trying to insert data intoo it. This is the error.  ***SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`smgt`.`payments`, CONSTRAINT `payments_studentid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`studentID`) REFERENCES `students` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `payments` (`studentID`, `feeType`, `Year`, `amount`, `paidBy`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (4662415, Hostel, 2016/2017, 2520, Kelvin Asamoah, 2020-04-11 09:19:45, 2020-04-11 09:19:45))***

Comment: @PrinceAsamoah That is a different question. But please read the docs. They are very good https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many. There is also a very good free video series https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch

Answer (score 2):

You have first add `foreign_key` then use `references`

```
$table->bigInteger('studentID')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('studentID')->references('id')->on('students');
```

Hope that it may problem your solve

Answer (score 0):

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('Programme');
            $table->string('cLevel');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('surName');
        });
    }

public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('studentID')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('studentID')->references('id')->on('students');
            $table->string('feeType');
            $table->string('Year');
            $table->double('amount', 15,3);
            $table->string('paidBy');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

You have to create studentId in the table where you create the foreign key.